# Azure pipeline fails node-gyp error at yarn install task

Tags: webdriver-io, node-gyp, azure-pipelines-tasks, azure-agent

I am running wdio test on azurepipelines on windows agent while upgrading from Node12 to Node14 getting error in yarn install any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to fix two things to resolve this as the above answer suggest I need to install python for all users in the azure agent

secondly I need to update the visual studio build tools to include the C++ development options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix python libraries and install python in ur system i faced the same error a while ago , fixed it with re-installing python